# How can I update the firmware of my Gravio USB Zigbee IoT Dongle?

Tags: usb, zigbee, dongle, gravio

How can I update the firmware of my [gravio.com IoT](https://www.gravio.com) USB dongle on a macOS?

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, the easiest is to use the HubKit `firmwareupdate` binary you can find in the `/Applications/Gravio\ HubKit.app/Contents/Resources/gssosx/` folder.

- Ensure that Gravio HubKit is not running
- Plugin the USB dongle
- List all devices using `ls -l | grep cu` which will give you the identifier of the USB dongle
- Use the command `sudo ./zigbeefirmwareupdate -f /path/to/firmware/file.bin -d /dev/cu.usbserial-Dxxxx`
- Wait for approximately 5 minutes for the program to finish